# vim ctags:tags not found if one space after lua function name

Tags: vim, lua, tags, macvim

I have commentted out all of my vimrc file, in my macOS (`22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul  5 22:22:05 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64 arm Darwin`), it cannot find tag with the folloing commands and source

```
$ cat x.lua
function test ()
end
$ ctags -R x.lua
$ cat tags
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
test    x.lua   /^function test ()$/;"  f

$ vim -t test
# vim reports the error like "E257: cstag: Tag not found"
```

If I removed the space after the function name `test`, like `function test()`, then it could work.

I also test this in my EC2 ubuntu, it could work even tough there is a space after the function name `test`.

I dont know how to debug after this, I also asked it to ChatGPT 3.5, but it could not resolve this.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem but Exuberant Ctags has been abandoned a while ago. Consider switching to [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io).

Comment: @Friedrich yea, after I switched to Universal Ctags, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing your file, `ctags` created a `test`  tag, *note the trailing space*, not a `test` tag. This is probably because the default parser for Lua doesn't expect optional whitespace between the name of the function and the opening parenthesis.

Since the actual tag is `test` , a search for `test` with `-t test` or `:tag test` won't work because the search is *literal*. You would have to…

- search for `test` , with the space, in Vim: `:tag test` ,
- or search for the regexp `test`: `:tag /test`

inside Vim, or:

- search for the regexp `test` from your shell: `$ vim -t /test`.

See `:help tag-regexp`.

If you can't remove that extraneous space from your code, which would be the real solution, here, you can tell ctags to search for new tags with a bit of regexp (see `$ man ctags`) or try [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/), as mentioned in the comments, which might or might not be smarter than Exuberant Ctags in this particular scenario.

Comment: Cool! Searching '/test' works for me. And at last I use `universal ctags` in my macOS to resolve this problem, ty!